# Spring Web service throws com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.BodyElement1_1Impl cannot be cast to org.jdom.Element

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I am totally new to Spring and started self studying from the begining as I want to develop as Spring-WS based web service.
 I have created `schemas.xsd, spring-ws-servlet.xml` and `web.xml` files in `WEB-INF` folder.
Also implemented the endpoint annotated with `@Endpoint`. 
In my `scehmas.xsd` I have below element

```
<xsd:element name="SimpleRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="reName" type="xsd:string" />                       
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
```

and in `web.xml` I specify the spring-ws message dispatcher servlet as below.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

In `spring-ws-servlet.xml` I define the endpoint

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />

<sws:annotation-driven />

<sws:dynamic-wsdl id="form" portTypeName="GUIForm"
    locationUri="/forms/">
    <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/schemas.xsd" />
</sws:dynamic-wsdl>

<bean id="formsEndpoint" class="com.test.FormsEndpoint"  />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping">
    <property name="defaultEndpoint" ref="formsEndpoint" />
</bean>
```

In my `FormsEndpoint` class I have the below method,

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "SimpleRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public Element handleFormsRequest(@RequestPayload Element simpleRequest) throws  JDOMException, ParserConfigurationException
            {

        System.out.println("================ Hit on Endpoint ========================");
        String formId = formIdExpression.valueOf(simpleRequest);

      }
```

At the line `formIdExpression.valueOf(simpleRequest);` it always throws

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.BodyElement1_1Impl cannot be cast to org.jdom.Element
    at org.jaxen.jdom.DocumentNavigator.getDocumentNode(DocumentNavigator.java:396)
    at org.jaxen.expr.DefaultAbsoluteLocationPath.evaluate(DefaultAbsoluteLocationPath.java:102)
    at org.jaxen.expr.DefaultXPathExpr.asList(DefaultXPathExpr.java:102)
    at org.jaxen.BaseXPath.selectNodesForContext(BaseXPath.java:674)
    at org.jaxen.BaseXPath.selectSingleNodeForContext(BaseXPath.java:698)
    at org.jaxen.BaseXPath.stringValueOf(BaseXPath.java:279)
    at org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath.valueOf(JaxenXPath.java:182)
    at com.neurotec.mmafis.FormsEndpoint.handleFormsRequest(FormsEndpoint.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.MethodEndpoint.invoke(MethodEndpoint.java:134)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.invokeInternal(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:240)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.invoke(AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:233)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:173)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I have tested a request using soapUI plugin in eclipse. Any ideas on why this occurs will highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a issue with `Jdom` when I started using `Jdom2` instead of `Jdom` issue got solved.

Answer (score 0):

you must first generate the classes corresponding to "SimpleRequest". You can use JAXB for this.

Then,

```
public Element handleFormsRequest(@RequestPayload Element simpleRequest)
```

should be

```
public Element handleFormsRequest(@RequestPayload **clazz** simpleRequest)
```

where clazz is the generated class